# Javascript: Tab Index - Focus

Tags: javascript

I need some help. It is all about tab index. I have a javascript that uses **document.getElementById("name").focus();** where the **textbox_1 with the id="name" is focus**. The problem is I uses a reload page that when I input a text in another **textbox_2 with id="test**" the page will reload and after reloading the tab index will be in the textbox_1, I want to do have an output that it will be stay at the textbox_2 after reloading.

Comment: Store a reference in a cookie, or local-storage that can be loaded when the page loads to signal your code which input box to highlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demonstrates how to save focus in localstorage when page is reloaded or re-visited.

http://jsfiddle.net/3w3h2z28/

```
 <input id="text1" type="text" onfocus="savefocus(this)">
 <input id="text2" type="text" onfocus="savefocus(this)">


var ls=window['localStorage'], 
    focus=ls.getItem("onfocus") || "text1",
    savefocus=function(e){ls.setItem("onfocus", e.id)};

    document.getElementById(focus).focus();
```