# focus input after reloading

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help, how can focus() a field (itself after fill) after reloading, since I already set another focus() a field in default.

```
<form>
  Default: <input type="text" name="reload_1" id="default"><br>
  Reload: <input type="text" name="reload_2" id="reload">
</form> 

<script>
  document.getElementById("default").focus();
</script>
```

The form has a script that after fill in the field since it is suggestion especially in id="reload" will reload, I want that to be focus not the id="default".

Comment: Your code should focus the field every time you (re)load the page.

Comment: And if you want focus on other field just change id in js

Comment: I answered that question two days ago

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281221/javascript-tab-index-focus/25281503#25281503

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could store a value in the window.name property to emulate a session variable

```
...
document.getElementById(window.name==='reload'?'reload':'default').focus();
window.name='reload';
...
```

http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/js-session/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I know the answer has already been choosen but why are we not going with "autofocus" attribute? It persists after page reload as well..

```
 <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" autofocus>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Save element id in localStorage.
2. OnLoad get element id from localStorage and set focus to element.

Answer (score 0):

put your code inside document.onload function

```
document.onload=function(){
 document.getElementById("default").focus();
}
```